# Optimizing c# code

Tags: c#-4.0

I have following code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var maxLetter = 4;
        List<string> wordList = new List<string>();
        Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>(); 
        string word = "Demo Deer Deep Deck Cere Reep Creep Creeps";
        string[] split = word.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < split.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                var common = split[i].Intersect(split[j]);
                var unCommon = split[i].Except(split[j]).Union(split[j].Except(split[i]));
                var count = common.Count() + unCommon.Count();
                if (count == maxLetter && split[i] != split[j])
                {
                    if (!wordList.Any(l => l == split[i]))
                    {
                        wordList.Add(split[i]);
                    }
                    wordList.Add(split[j]);
                }                
            }
            if (wordList.Count > 0)
            {
                dic.Add(i, String.Join("\n", wordList));
                wordList.Clear();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", dic));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I am trying to get result in a way like:

```
[1, Deer Deep Cere]
[2, Deep Deer Reep]
[4, Cere Deer Creep]
[5, Reep Deep]
[6, Creep Cere]
```

Above code works for small number of letters but as soon as i increase the letters lets say to 500 it stops working. Is there a way to optimize it or make it more simpler so it works quickly?

Comment: `it stops working` <= what does that mean and be specific.

Comment: @Igor - I think it is taking long time to run through the logic so it times out.

Comment: This question should be edited to explain what the algorithm is intended to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Your process is probably taking to long.  You shouldn’t have processes that take this long to run on the main thread.  Run the code in a new Thread or Task and it should run just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add using System.Threading.Tasks;

Task task = Task.Run(() => {

```
 Your Code Here
```

});

Console. Readline();

Make sure the Console.Readline is outside the task to keep the Console open.